# Make a text-link in SVG via Adobe Illustrator

Tags: hyperlink, svg, adobe-illustrator, xlink

When linking-out text, I save the graphics as **Tiny-SVG**, and embed the text-passage in a `tspan` element and wrap this `tspan` using the `<a xlink:href="http://....">`. It works but I would like to know more about alternatives, and *pros/cons* compared to using other elements such as groups: `g`.

**Questions**

1. Is there a quick way to do this directly in Adobe Illustrator CS 4+ ?
2. What do you use to make links? (markup-wise, that is)

**Reference Code**

```
  <text font-size="6">created by 
    <a xlink:href="https://github.com/..."><tspan>{APPNAME}</tspan></a>
    {APPVERSION}
  </text>
```

**Links**

[W3C: 17.2 Links out of SVG content: the ‘a’ element](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/linking.html#Links)

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't know
2. You can wrap any rendering svg elements in an <a> element, e.g if you want you can wrap the whole <text> element in it, or even include some shapes. It depends on what you want to make clickable.

Answer (score 0):

I recently tried to do this in Illustrator too, and found [a good answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27497/add-a-hyperlink-within-illustrator/27500#comment62545_27500) on the Graphic Design Stack Exchange forum.  However, Illustrator seems a little buggy to me (check my comment there) when doing this.  Further, I found that if I open and edit an existing svg in Illustrator, it didn't preserve the links when it saved out the revision.